# Check whether base64 string is a GIF image

Tags: c#, image, base64

I have a base64 encoded string and I want to find out whether that string contains a GIF image or not.

How will I do that in C#?

Answer (score 4):

1. Decode from base 64.
2. [Examine the file header](http://www.mikekunz.com/image_file_header.html).
3. If the first three bytes are `GIF`, it's a GIF.

Comment: Any way to determine if it's a PNG?

Comment: @PeterX Scan the first 8 bytes. If they're `137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10` (decimal), it's a PNG. [Source](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Rationale.html#R.PNG-file-signature).